# Navigation bar CSS is not properly displayed in Firefox but it's OK with IE

Tags: css

navigation bar css not properly display in firefox but its ok with IE

css code

```
#topnav ul
{
    display:table;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

    overflow:hidden;
}

#topnav li
{   

    float:left;

}

#topvav a:link,
#topnav a:visited
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:calibri;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#topnav a:hover,
#topnav a:active
{
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

html code

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">OPD</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">IPD</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">Infrastucture</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#news">Media</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#contact">Site Map</a></li>
    <li id="topnav"><a  href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>


</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `id`s not properly. **ID's** have to be **unique** for the whole page.
Also you do not need `li` elements with ids. You can access the `li` elements by CSS like this.

```
#topnav li
```

Then, your selector `#topnav ul` is not valid. it should be `ul#topnav` (as far as what I can see from your posted HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Change "`float: left;`" in `#topnav` `li` to "`display: inline;`".